# Assigning Values Using Logical Operators

Tags: r, logical-operators

I am trying to code weekends and weekdays using numeric values, such that "Monday","Tuesday",..."Friday" = 0 and "Saturday"/"Sunday" = 1. I presently have the following data:

> head(bike.d)

```
    Day    Day.Code
    Sunday     4
    Sunday     4
    Sunday     4
    Sunday     4
    Sunday     4
    Sunday     4
```

tail(bike.d)

```
    Day    Day.Code
    Saturday   3
    Saturday   3
    Saturday   3
    Saturday   3
    Saturday   3
    Saturday   3
```

I have coded the Day column numerically using:

> Day.Code = as.numeric(bike.d$Day)

Where Friday = 1, Monday = 2, Saturday = 3, Sunday = 4, Thursday = 5, Tuesday =6, Wednesday = 7.

I have tried to use logical operators to assign the binary values with weekdays =0 and weekends = 1.  I have tried variations of the following argument, but I get the following output:

```
bike.d[,2 == 3|4]=1

head(bike.d)

    Day    Day.Code
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
```

> tail(bike.d)

```
    Day    Day.Code
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
     1         1
```

Is there a way I can create this argument so that the text values in the "Day" column is preserved?  And so that the binary code is either input in the Day.code column, or a new column?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Look at `merge`, it will make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

An `ifelse` should be exactly what you need here (there are *many* other ways to do it):

```
bike.d$Weekend <- ifelse( bike.d$Day.Code == 3 | bike.d$Day.Code == 4 , 1 , 0 )
```

An example:

```
bike.d<- data.frame( Day = rep( weekdays(Sys.Date()+1:7) , each = 2 ) , Day.Code = rep( 1:7 , each = 2 ) )
bike.d$Weekend <- ifelse( bike.d$Day.Code == 3 | bike.d$Day.Code == 4 , 1 , 0 )
bike.d
#        Day Day.Code Weekend
#1   Thursday        1       0
#2   Thursday        1       0
#3     Friday        2       0
#4     Friday        2       0
#5   Saturday        3       1
#6   Saturday        3       1
#7     Sunday        4       1
#8     Sunday        4       1
#9     Monday        5       0
#10    Monday        5       0
#11   Tuesday        6       0
#12   Tuesday        6       0
#13 Wednesday        7       0
#14 Wednesday        7       0
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I keep getting the following error:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Weekend", value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 74847

Comment: @user2339597 That doesn't mean a lot without the command you ran and the structure of your data. Please update your question with the output from running this command in R `dput( head(bike.d , n = 30 ) )`.